# Angular 4 case with routing and responsive mode

Tags: css, angular, http, url, routes

I have created an instance of `ubuntu` server on `AWS`. Everything works prettey fine beyond two things which are not fully understand by me.

1. When you go to [my web app](http://18.194.246.12:8091) you have to operate only on `buttons` which are e.g in menu. You can't make a request like `'mypage/items'` because it throws `HTTP 404 Error`. But if you go to bookmark called `Home` you should notice it added to the `url` the suffix `/items`. But in my `app.module` every route is defined:

   ```
      `RouterModule.forRoot([
             { path: 'items', component: ItemListComponent},
             { path: 'guide', component: GuideComponent},
             { path: 'history', component: HistoryComponent},
             { path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent},
             { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
             { path: '', component: ItemListComponent}
           ])`
   ```

   `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li routerLinkActive="active current"><a routerLink="/items">Home</a></li>
         <li routerLinkActive="active current"><a routerLink="/guide">Poradnik</a></li>
         <li routerLinkActive="active current"><a routerLink="/history">Historia</a></li>
       </ul>`
2. Are you able to provide me some tip how can I make my `table` which is at `Home` bookmark responsive? It doens't like goot when you switch to mobile devices mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a configuration to the web server to redirect all your requests to index.html for your web app. Please use the following link for your reference: 
https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: What are you using locally to host the angular 4 app?

Comment: `Spring Boot` is behind